# Trying to Count the Number of Operations in Code

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have recently been reading Sedgewick's Algorithms Book, and I came across an example I didn't quite understand...

[image: The code in question]

Using this code, Sedgewick mentions that the if statement is run precisely 
**N x (N-1)(N-2)/6 times**.

I don't quite understand why that is.... I see that there are the triple nested loops, each with an upper bound that is increasing, but why is the value divided by six?

Comment: The problem iterates over all distinct index ordered triples `(i, j, k)` and no triple repeats. There are `n choose 3 = n*(n-1)*(n-2)/6` such triples.

Comment: Whoa.. I'm Sorry @hilberts_drinking_problem I could find this comment until I posted itㅠㅠ  I apologize for this and hope you have a great day

Comment: No harm done, I like your graphic!

Comment: Thanks guys! Appreciate both of your answers (hilberts and J4BEZ). Didn't realize this would end up being a combinatorics problem! Haha

Comment: Wolfram alpha makes short work of these calculations: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28sum%28sum%281+for+k+%3D+j%2B1...+N-1%29+for+j+in+i%2B1+...+N-1%29+for+i+%3D+0+...+N-1%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ask for your understanding that I am not good at math, so the explanation may be a little bit cheesy.

In order to '`if(a[i] + j[i] + k[i])` statement' inside the code be executed The variables i, j, and k that point out an array 'a' index in Tripple for loop  must fit the condition of the statement `(0<= i <j<k <N)`, right?

For example, N is 4.
[image]
It seems to be available through the permutation (4P3 = 4^3) that selects three of the four, but if 4 is selected in 'i' as shown in the picture above, you can see that progress is blocked in 'j' for-loop (j = 4+1; j<4; j++).

So We can't get the number of times an if statement will run with a simple sequence.

What we need is a **combination ([nCr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination))**.

When index flows from 0 to N-1,
The number of cases (i,j,k) that satisfy `i < j < k`(=> if statement can run) can be obtained by the formula nC3.

[image]
According to this formula, if statement is **run precisely N x (N-1)(N-2)/6 times**

I hope you understand it well and if you don't, please leave a comment!
Have a nice day!